# Pip not installed?

Tags: 16.04, python, pip

Ok. I know what you are thinking. It is an already asked question. Just mark it as multiple and move on. BUT... I have installed python-pip, and when I try to do something using PIP, it says I don't have it.

```
    sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

THEN....

```
    python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
    /usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

Please help! 
 I have Ubuntu 16.04, by the way.

Comment: You need to install `pip` for Python 3 instead by running `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`.

Answer (score 8):

For using `pip` in `python3` you need to run this command to install `pip` module also for `python3`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, it installed without a problem, but then the above problem occurred again. Thanks for stopping by!

Comment: I know this is an old answer but it popped up first on my search. For anyone else in the same boat: Python 3 pip uses the pip3 command.

pip3 install <package name>